# Is it possible to use methods inside String format to use in java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to convert code like this

```
for (Contacto contact : contactos) {
    fix.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", 
        contact.getName(), contact.getNumb(), contact.getDateOfBirth());
}
```

into a java stream?

Comment: Yes, but why would you?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can - the below should do the trick, using the [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) method of `Stream`:

```
contactos.stream()
         .forEach(c -> fix.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", c.getName(), c.getNumb(), c.getDoB()));
```

Bear in mind this can impair readability - most people I know would say the loop is easier to read than this.

Also bear in mind that reaaaaally, for this, you should use [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead of `forEach` - `forEach` doesn't guarantee the order in which the items are processed, and for parallel streams this matters. `forEachOrdered` guarantees that items are processed one-by-one.

---

You can omit the call to `Stream`, depending on your container - if it implements [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (most standard containers do), then you should use [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) on that rather than the stream (so `contactos.forEach(...)`. It's tidier and avoids the overhead of creating a `Stream`.

You also avoid the `forEachOrdered` issue above, as the items are processed "in iteration order".

Comment: Note that there is overhead in creating a stream, so if your container _does_ implement `Iterable`, then you really _should_ leave out the call to `stream()`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Yeah, I focused on `Stream` as OP specifically asked for that. Assuming they're just wanting fancier syntax than a loop, then hopefully they'll decide to use `Iterable`'s version instead, agreed. I'll change a few words to emphasise it's a better choice, though.

Comment: no need stream can use like contactos.forEach(c -> fix.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", c.getName(), c.getNumb(), c.getDoB()));

Comment: @janith1024 Yes, that's what the second part of my answer explains.